# Exception handling and blank page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was reading about Datastore exception handling [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors) and possible errors [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors) but I am having problems implementing it. Here's an example code of what I made.

```
try:
    example.put()
except datastore_errors.TransactionFailedError:
    self.response.write('Transaction failed, try again.')
```

When I try to load my page, nothing appears. I have built a little interface for interacting with my databases but that doesn't show up. If I remove the try/except statements, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?
Also why nothing at all is displayed? Shouldn't it display at least the HTML template and just throw an error when I try to put something in the database?

*EDIT*
Added handler code, more info

What I am doing here is I have a page where I choose a database. Depending on my choice, I open up a template I've made for adding easily instances to that database. So far I've made a template only for one database. I'm also using MathJax library and have check button to check the input before posting it.

When I implement the try/except statement, nothings gets rendered at all. Even the first page, which uses a completely different handler. I want to know why and also what's wrong with the try/except statement.

Hope that helps.

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        page = env.get_template('main.html')
        self.response.out.write(page.render())

class DatabaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        database = self.request.get('db')
        mathPage = env.get_template('mp_database.html')
        menuPage = env.get_template('mi_database.html')
        if database == 'mathproblem':
            self.response.write(mathPage.render())
        elif database == 'menuitem':
            self.response.write(menuPage.render())

    def post(self):
            submit = self.request.get('submit')
            if submit == 'Submit':
                page = env.get_template('mp_database.html')
                problem = self.request.get('problem')
                problem_db = MathProblem(task=problem)
                problem_db.put()
                value = {'added': '\(' + problem + '\)' + ' ' 'added'}
                self.response.write(page.render(value))

            elif submit == 'Check':
                page = env.get_template('mp_database.html')
                problem = self.request.get('problem')
                values = {'displayed': '$$' + problem + '$$',
                      'problem': problem, 'text': 'Problem'}
                self.response.write(page.render(values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/database', DatabaseHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit ?

Comment: You have to provide more info.. can you also show us what do you have after this code till the end of your handler?

Comment: check the logs. I don't see where you put the try/catch in your code